# LWUIT - Adding 3 Commands and how to get events from them?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-resource-editor, lwuit-button, lwuit-command

I was working with Command Component with LWUIT to develop small Midlet applications
there was a situation where i had to have three commands helping me to go to different forms.

Display.getInstance().setThirdSoftButton(true); definetly helped in displaying the 3 commands.
Since i am using the Sun Wireless toolkit for CLDC 2.5.2 , It gives mobile emulators with only two soft keys.

Please help me with getting the event from 3rd key also...

eagerly waiting for reply..

Thanks and regards,
Swati

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fire button for the 3rd command.